# python threading and shared variables

Tags: python, thread-safety, queue

how can i update a shared variable between different threading.Thread in python?

lets say that i have 5 threads working down a Queue.Queue(). after the queue is done i want to do an other operation but i want it to happen only once.

is it possible to share and update a variable betweeen the threads. so when Queue.empty() is True this event gets fired but if one of the threads is doing it i dont want the others to do do that too because i would get wrong results.

**EDIT**
i have a queue which reflects files on the filesystem. 
the files are uploaded to a site by the threads and while each thread is uploading the file it updates a set() of keywords i got from the files.
when the queue is empty i need to contact the site and tell it to update the keyword counts. right now each thread does this and i get an update for each thread which is bad. 
i also tried to empty the set but it doesnt work.

```
    keywordset = set()
    hkeywordset = set()
    def worker():
        while queue:
            if queue.empty():
                if len(keywordset) or len(hkeywordset):
                    # as soon as the queue is empty we send the keywords and hkeywords to the
                    # imageapp so it can start updating 
                    apiurl   = update_cols_url
                    if apiurl[-1] != '/':
                        apiurl = apiurl+'/'
                    try:
                        keywords = []
                        data = dict(keywords=list(keywordset), hkeywords=list(hkeywordset))
                        post = dict(data=simplejson.dumps(data))
                        post = urllib.urlencode(post)
                        urllib2.urlopen(apiurl, post)
                        hkeywordset.clear()
                        keywordset.clear()
                        print 'sent keywords and hkeywords to imageapp...'
                    except Exception, e: print e
            # we get the task form the Queue and process the file based on the action
            task = queue.get()
            print str(task)
            try:
                reindex = task['reindex']
            except:
                reindex = False
            data = updater.process_file(task['filename'], task['action'], task['fnamechange'], reindex)
            # we parse the images keywords and hkeywords and add them to the sets above for later 
            # processing
            try:
                for keyword in data['keywords']:
                    keywordset.add(keyword)
            except: pass
            try:
                for hkw in data['hkeywords']:
                        hkeywordset.add(hkw)
            except:pass
            queue.task_done()


    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    while 1:
        line = raw_input('type \'q\' to stop filewatcher... or \'qq\' to force quit...\n').strip()
```

this is what i was trying basically. but of course the part of queue.empty() gets exectued as many times as threads i have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a queue to run your thread ([thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)) so you are making sure that there will not be a race condition (thread safe) because the queue run your thread in a sequential way, so i think you can share a variable between the thread and you can be sure that there will not be a race condition over this variable.

**Edit** : Here is something similar about what you want to do hope this can give you answer to your question this time :) :

```
import Queue
import threading
import ftplib
import os


class SendFileThread(threading.Thread):
     """ Thread that will handle sending files to the FTP server"""

     # Make set of keywords a class variable.
     Keywords = set()

     def __init__(self, queue, conn):

          self.conn = conn   
          self.queue = queue

          threading.Thread.__init__(self)

      def run(self):
          while True:
              # Grabs file from queue.
              file_name = self.queue.get()

              # Send file to FTP server.
              f=open(file_name,'rb')
              self.conn.storbinary('STOR '+os.path.basename(file_name),f)

              # Suppose that this keywords are in the first line.
              # Update the set of keywords.
              SendFileThread.Keywords.update(f.readline().split(" ")))

              # Signals to queue job is done.
              self.queue.task_done()


def main():
     # Files to send.
     files = os.listdir('/tosend')

     queue = Queue.Queue()

     # Connect to the FTP server.
     conn = ftplib.FTP('ftp_uri')   
     conn.login()

     # Create 5 threads that will handle file to send.
     for i in range(5):
         t = SendFileThread(queue, conn)
         t.start()

     # Fill the queue with files to be send.   
     for file in files:
         queue.put(file)

     # Wait until or thread are finish
     queue.join()

     # Send the keywords to the FTP server.
     # I didn't understand well the part update keywords count, 
     # how this count is stored ...
     # Here i will just send the keywords to the FTP server.
     with open("keywords", "w") as keywords_file
         keywords_file.write(";".join(SendFileThread.Keywords))
         conn.storbinary('STOR '+os.path.basename("keywords"),
                          keywords_file)

     conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: sorry but i really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @aschmid00 : __sorry but i really don't understand what you mean__ it's the same for me ? i meant to help but i think rather that i just make you more confused, i think i will delete this answer unless you give us more detail about what you want to do and maybe some code to understand more the problem , Hope you find your answers :)

Comment: yes this helped to understand it a bit more. the difference to mine is that the threads are always alive because im listening to filesystem events and upload a file if it is dropped in the watched folder. an eventwatcher adds the tasks to the queue and the threads work on the tasks.

Comment: ...but i still didn't find a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just add the final step to the queue ?

Comment: thats what im trying to with empty() where i process data in a set() and do the final test. the problem is that if i have multiple threads this final step is processed once for each thread. i want it to happen only once.

Answer (score 0):

Have another queue where you place this event after first queue is empty.
Or have special thread for this event.